# How to check if radio button is selected or not using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
<div class="my_account_module_content">
<h3 class="my_account_module_content_title">
Mi Dirección 1
<br>
<span>Predeterminada</span>

<div class="selectCard_left">
<input id="17390233" class="default_shipping_address" type="radio" name="address" checked="true">
<span>Seleccionar como tarjeta predeterminada</span>
</div>
```

this is the HTML code

If radio button selected is true then print the class span value?
please help me..

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! I've formatted the code in your question so that it outputs correctly now. It seems though that your mark-up is invalid — is this the mark-up in your page, or was it an error copying & pasting? Also, please add more detail to your question around what you've tried & what has gone wrong in your previous attempts. People are happy to help, but a 'please give me all of the code' question won't be met with a great response.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, this would do it:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("17390233")).isSelected()){
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='17390233']/following-sibling::span[1]")).getText());
}
```

If the radio button is selected, then the text will show. If you want to use the text somewhere, I suggest you put it in a string instead:

```
String spanText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='17390233']/following-sibling::span[1]")).getText();
```

Hope this answers your question.

EDIT: Here is an update of other ways to try.

If the className `default_shipping_address` is unique (e.g. not used anywhere else on the page), you may try locating the element by *className*:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.className("default_shipping_address")).isSelected()){
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='default_shipping_address']/following-sibling::span[1]")).getText());
}
```

If that class is not unique, maybe the DIV's className `selectCard_left` is?

```
if(driver.findElement(By.className("selectCard_left"))){
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='selectCard_left']/span[1]")).getText());
}
```

If none of the classNames are unique, a complete xpath expression is required. If you still are unable to get that text, I refer to reading up on how to use xpath: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

I hope that you find this information useful.

Comment: Hi i am getting the error Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"17390233"}

Comment: Then it would seem that the ID is auto-generated and different each time. Is the class `default_shipping_address` present anywhere else on the page?

Comment: can we try like if checked= true then print the class value? checked="true">
<span>Seleccionar como tarjeta predeterminada</span>

Comment: @user3538483 You can do that, but first you need to locate the element. Since the id is dynamic, you can try doing it by class if default_shipping_address is unique. If not, you have to try xpath or cssselector to locate the element. Once you figure out a way to locate the element, you can use the above code to print span.

Comment: @user3538483 Please tick this answer as accepted if it helped you :-)