# How to check a radio button with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

I want to check this radio button, but I didn't know how.
My HTML is:

```
<div class="appendContent">

    <div> id="contentContainer" class="grid_list_template">
        <div id="routeMonitorOptions"></div>
    </div>

    <input id="optionStopGrid" type="radio" name="gridSelector"/>
    <label for="optionStopGrid">Paradas</label>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if radio button is selected or not using Selenium WebDriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362768/how-to-check-if-radio-button-is-selected-or-not-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class answer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.example.com/");
        //If u want to know the number of radio buttons then use List
        List<WebElement>radioButton = driver.findElements(By.tagName("example"));
        System.out.println(radioButton.size());
        //If u want to select the radio button
        driver.findElement(By.id("example")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //If u want the Text in U R console
        for(int i=0;i<radioButton.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(radioButton.get(i).getText());
        } 
        //If u want to check whether the radio button is selected or not
        if(driver.findElement(By.id("example")).isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try this code to select the radiobutton-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='optionStopGrid']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362768/how-to-check-if-radio-button-is-selected-or-not-using-selenium-webdriver) should definitely help you.

You can find the element easily by id, then you just have to call the `isSelected` method.

Comment: What did you try exactly ? Could you edit your first message to show us the Java code that didn't work ?

Comment: List<WebElement> radio = driver.findElements(By.id("optionStopGrid"));
  radio.get(2).getAttribute("checked");

Comment: I can't make the radio button is selected

Comment: An id must be unique in a web page. So, you shouldn't call findElements (plural) but findElement (singular), there must be one and only one element with this id in the web page. So the `radio` becomes : `WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.id("optionStopGrid"));` then you just have to call `radio.isSelected();` as mentionned in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Before selecting elements use time.sleep() or implicit() or explicit () wait then
driver.find_element_by_id("profile_id_2559380").click()

Comment: Suggestion : add code samples to highlight the code and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm showing up late to the party but I wanted to add my two cents.
Sometimes, the simple `.click()` won't work because what you've selected is the `input` tag, when in reality it's the attached `span` tag that we as humans click on.
What you can do in those cases where you have the `input` tag is go up to the parent and then find the sibling `span` to click, like so:

```java
optionInput.parent().$("span").click();
```