# How to read the text from the selected radio button and how to select the other radio button?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to read the selected radio button text and I want to select another radio box so  I am reading all 3 radio buttons text and passing to strings and trying to select the radio button which is not selected, but using if condition not able to do it, please help me to select the checkbox.

This is the HTML code

```html
<ul class="custom-ul">
    <li class="custom-li custom-radio m-subscriptions-padding receive-VIP1">
        <input name="email-preferences" id="receive-VIP" type="radio" value="receive-VIP1">
        <input name="_D:email-preferences" type="hidden" value=" ">                       <label for="receive-VIP" class="custom-radio-label">
             <span class="label-alt-text">Receive special offers via email</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="custom-li custom-radio m-subscriptions-padding receive-fewer1">
        <input name="email-preferences" checked="checked" id="receive-fewer" type="radio" value="receive-fewer1" class="radio-checked">
        <input name="_D:email-preferences" type="hidden" value=" ">
        <label for="receive-fewer" class="custom-radio-label">
             <span class="label-alt-text">Receive fewer emails. We won't email you more than one time per week.</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="custom-li custom-radio m-subscriptions-padding receive-no-emails">
        <input name="email-preferences" id="receive-no-emails" type="radio" value="receive-no-emails">
        <input name="_D:email-preferences" type="hidden" value=" ">
        <label for="receive-no-emails" class="custom-radio-label">
             <span class="label-alt-text"> Unsubscribe: we will remove you from all testdevv promotional emails.</span>
        </label>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: <ul class="custom-ul">
                            <li class="custom-li custom-radio m-subscriptions-padding receive-VIP1">
                                <input name="email-preferences" id="receive-VIP" type="radio" value="receive-VIP1"><input name="_D:email-preferences" type="hidden" value=" "><label for="receive-VIP" class="custom-radio-label"> <span class="label-alt-text">Receive special offers via email</span>
                            </label>
                            </li>

Comment: <li class="custom-li custom-radio m-subscriptions-padding receive-fewer1">
                                <input name="email-preferences" checked="checked" id="receive-fewer" type="radio" value="receive-fewer1" class="radio-checked"><input name="_D:email-preferences" type="hidden" value=" "><label for="receive-fewer" class="custom-radio-label"> <span class="label-alt-text">Receive fewer emails. We won't email you more than one time per week.</span></label>
                            </li>

Comment: <li class="custom-li custom-radio m-subscriptions-padding receive-no-emails">
                                <input name="email-preferences" id="receive-no-emails" type="radio" value="receive-no-emails"><input name="_D:email-preferences" type="hidden" value=" "><label for="receive-no-emails" class="custom-radio-label">
                                    <span class="label-alt-text"> Unsubscribe: we will remove you from all testdevv promotional emails.</span>
                            </label>
                            </li>
         These are the 3 li tags for the 3 radio buttons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a radio button with Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997365/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: No in my case I want read the selected radio button text and I want to select any other radio button which is not selected out of 3

Comment: I am able to read the selected radio button text but how itarate the radio button selection for each test run

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("url here");
        List<WebElement> radioButtons = driver.findElements(By.name("email-preferences"));
        for (int i = 0; i < radioButtons.size(); i++) {
            if (driver.findElement(By.name("email-preferences")).isSelected()) {
                System.out.println(radioButtons.get(i).getText());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the selected option text and all the available options list as below.

Please use the below logic in your code

**Code:**

```
    //If none of the option is selected, then exception will be thrown and to avoid this we can use findElements method
    List<WebElement> radioButtonSelectedList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='radio-checked']//parent::*//span"));
    String selectedValue="";
    ArrayList<String> optionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(radioButtonSelectedList.size()!=0){
        //If the button is selected, then we can get the selected option text
        selectedValue=radioButtonSelectedList.get(0).getText();

        //To get all the available Options
        List<WebElement> optionsElement=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='custom-ul']//span"));

        for(WebElement element: optionsElement){
            optionsElement.add(element);
        }

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("None of the option is selected");
    }

    System.out.println("Available Options :"+optionsList);
    System.out.println("Selected Option :"+selectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try next solution:

```
    //this is row with radiobutton and text
    private By customRadioElement = By.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'custom-radio')]");
    //this is all radiobuttons
    private By radiobutton = By.xpath("./input[@name='email-preferences']");
    //this is all labels for radiobuttons
    private By radiobuttonLabel = By.xpath("./label/span");

    public void selectRadiobutton(String labelText) {
        List<WebElement> tempList = driver.findElements(customRadioElement);
        for (WebElement element : tempList) {
            //webElement can search for elements, and if xpath locator starts with "." element will search for element from his children
            if (labelText.equals(element.findElement(radiobuttonLabel).getText())) {
                element.findElement(radiobutton).click();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getSelectedRadiobuttonLabelText() {
        List<WebElement> tempList = driver.findElements(customRadioElement);
        for (WebElement element : tempList) {
            //webElement can search for elements, and if xpath locator starts with "." element will search for element from his children
            if (element.findElement(radiobutton).isSelected()) {
                return element.findElement(radiobuttonLabel).getText();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```