# How to count number of radio buttons is clicked in selenium

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

I have a screen with Table1. When the radio buttons are clicked on atleast one column, then my logic works. But when the screen looks like Table2, my logic is failing at the second if statement as it was not able to fetch the number of clicked radios in 'error'. I need to find out how many radio buttons are clicked for 'Defect', 'Error' 'Learning Opportunity'. Could someone help me how to make a generalize logic that will work for any type of screen displays.

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

My logic

```
String reviewBorrowerAndCoborrowerOnlyTable = "//table[@id='borrowerAndCoborrowerOnlyTable']/tbody/tr/td";
        int defectBorrowerSize = 0, errorBorrowerSize = 0, learningOpportunityBorrowerSize = 0;

        if (!driver.findElements(By.xpath(reviewBorrowerAndCoborrowerOnlyTable + "/input[@value='defect' and @aria-checked='true']")).isEmpty())
        {
            List<WebElement> defectBorrower = driver.findElements(By.xpath(reviewBorrowerAndCoborrowerOnlyTable + "/input[@value='defect' and @aria-checked='true']"));
            defectBorrowerSize = defectBorrower.size();
            System.out.println("The total selected Defect radio buttons is : " + defectBorrowerSize);
        }

        if (!driver.findElements(By.xpath(reviewBorrowerAndCoborrowerOnlyTable + "/input[@value='error' and @aria-checked='true']")).isEmpty())
        {
            List<WebElement> errorBorrower = driver.findElements(By.xpath(reviewBorrowerAndCoborrowerOnlyTable + "/input[@value='error' and @aria-checked='true']"));
            errorBorrowerSize = errorBorrower.size();
        }

        if (!driver.findElements(By.xpath(reviewBorrowerAndCoborrowerOnlyTable + "/input[@value='learningOpportunity' and @aria-checked='true']")).isEmpty())
        {
            List<WebElement> learningOpportunityBorrower = driver.findElements(By.xpath(reviewBorrowerAndCoborrowerOnlyTable + "/input[@value='learningOpportunity' and @aria-checked='true']"));
            learningOpportunityBorrowerSize = learningOpportunityBorrower.size();
        }

        int result = defectBorrowerSize + errorBorrowerSize + learningOpportunityBorrowerSize;
```

and inspected AnjularJS code looks like below.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="borrowerAndCoborrowerOnlyTable">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="5">
                                    Borrower <br>
                                    <span class="boldCaseData ng-binding">ATDDCBRFNameTwentyThree ATDDCBRLNameTwentyThree</span>
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="5">
                                    Co-Borrower <br>
                                    <span class="boldCaseData"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Processor Validation</td>
                                <td>Satisfactory</td>
                                <td>Learning Opportunity</td>
                                <td>Error</td>
                                <td>Defect</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Processor Validation</td>
                                <td>Satisfactory</td>
                                <td>Learning Opportunity</td>
                                <td>Error</td>
                                <td>Defect</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="labelColumn">Borrower/Coborrower on account verification</td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="borrowerCoborrowerYesVerifcationPeerReviewRadio" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="217" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="borrowerCoborrowerYesVerifcationPeerReviewRadio" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="218" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="borrowerCoborrowerYesVerifcationPeerReviewRadio" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="219" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="borrowerCoborrowerYesVerifcationPeerReviewRadio" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="220" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr data-ng-show="nameRadioBorrower" aria-hidden="false">
                                <td class="labelColumn">Name (First, Middle and Last)</td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="namePeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="221" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="namePeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="222" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="namePeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="223" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="namePeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="224" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                                <td></td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="namePeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="225" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="namePeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="226" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="namePeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="227" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="namePeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="228" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr data-ng-show="generationCodeRadioBorrower" aria-hidden="false">
                                <td class="labelColumn">Generation Code</td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="generationCodePeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="229" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="generationCodePeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="230" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="generationCodePeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="231" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="generationCodePeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="232" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="generationCodePeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="233" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="generationCodePeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="234" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="generationCodePeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="235" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="generationCodePeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="236" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr data-ng-show="ssnRadioBorrower" aria-hidden="false">
                                <td class="labelColumn">SSN</td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="ssnPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="237" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="ssnPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="238" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="ssnPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="239" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="ssnPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="240" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="ssnPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="241" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="ssnPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="242" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="ssnPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="243" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="ssnPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="244" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr data-ng-show="dobRadioBorrower" aria-hidden="false">
                                <td class="labelColumn">DOB</td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="dobPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="245" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="dobPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="246" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="dobPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="247" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="dobPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="248" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                                <td></td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="dobPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="249" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="dobPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="250" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="dobPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="251" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="dobPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="252" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr data-ng-show="telephoneNumberRadioBorrower" aria-hidden="false">
                                <td class="labelColumn">Telephone Number</td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="telephoneNumberPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="253" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="telephoneNumberPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="254" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="telephoneNumberPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="255" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="telephoneNumberPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="256" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                                <td></td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="telephoneNumberPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="257" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="telephoneNumberPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="258" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="telephoneNumberPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="259" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="telephoneNumberPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="260" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr data-ng-show="ecoaCodeRadioBorrower" aria-hidden="false">
                                <td class="labelColumn">ECOA</td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="ecoaPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="261" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="ecoaPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="262" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="ecoaPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="263" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="ecoaPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="264" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                                <td></td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="ecoaPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="265" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="ecoaPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="266" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="ecoaPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="267" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="ecoaPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="268" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr data-ng-show="caseToOpen.disputeType == 'Direct'" aria-hidden="false">
                                <td class="labelColumn">Property Address (City, State and Zip)</td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="propertyAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="269" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="propertyAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="270" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="propertyAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="271" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="propertyAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="272" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                                <td></td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="propertyAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="273" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="propertyAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="274" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="propertyAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="275" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="propertyAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="276" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr data-ng-show="caseToOpen.disputeType == 'Direct'" aria-hidden="false">
                                <td class="labelColumn">Mailing Address (City, State and Zip)</td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="mailingAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="277" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="mailingAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="278" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="mailingAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="279" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="mailingAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="280" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                                <td></td>

                                <td class="ng-binding">YES</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="mailingAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="281" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="mailingAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="282" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="mailingAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="283" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="mailingAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="284" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr data-ng-show="caseToOpen.disputeType == 'Indirect' &amp;&amp; previousAddressRadioBorrower" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-hide">
                                <td class="labelColumn">Previous Address (City, State and Zip)</td>

                                <td class="ng-binding"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="previousAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="285" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="previousAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="286" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="previousAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="287" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="previousAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="288" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                                <td></td>

                                <td class="ng-binding"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="previousAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="289" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="previousAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="290" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="previousAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="291" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="previousAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="292" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr data-ng-show="caseToOpen.disputeType == 'Indirect' &amp;&amp; currentAddressRadioBorrower" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-hide">
                                <td class="labelColumn">Current Address (City, State and Zip)</td>

                                <td class="ng-binding"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="currentAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="293" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="currentAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="294" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="currentAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="295" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="currentAddressPeerReviewRadioBorrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="296" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                                <td></td>

                                <td class="ng-binding"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="satisfactory" data-ng-model="currentAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="297" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="learningOpportunity" data-ng-model="currentAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="298" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="error" data-ng-model="currentAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="299" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" value="defect" data-ng-model="currentAddressPeerReviewRadioCoborrower" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="300" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-invalid="false"></td>

                            </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Please try to trim out unnecessary code

Comment: any help is appreciated please...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362768/how-to-check-if-radio-button-is-selected-or-not-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

Here i have written some code. Please check

```
public static void RadioTest()
{
    FirefoxDriver driver;        
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //your URL
    driver.get("YOUR URL "); 

    //Get All Readio Button from document
    List<WebElement> listAllRadioButtons= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='radio']"));

    //Get All Readio Button Checked from document
    List<WebElement> listAllRadioButtonsChecked= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='radio']:checked"));

    //Get All Readio Button from table
    List<WebElement> listAllRadioButtonsFromTable = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table>tbody>tr>td>input[type='radio']"));

    //Get All Readio Button Checked from table
    List<WebElement> listAllRadioButtonsFromTableChecked = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table>tbody>tr>td>input[type='radio']:checked"));

    //Get All td of specfic column
    int colNumber = 3;
    List<WebElement> listCol = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child("+colNumber+")"));

    //Get All Radio Button of specfic column
    //for example in your case to get all radio button of Defects
    colNumber=6;
    List<WebElement> listColRadioButton = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child("+colNumber+")>input[type='radio']"));

    //Get All Radio Button Checked of specfic column
    //for example in your case to get all radio button of Defects
    colNumber=6;
    List<WebElement> listColRadioButtonChecked = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child("+colNumber+")>input[type='radio']:checked"));


    //Get All Radio Button of specfic Row
    //for example in your case to get all radio button of SSN ROW
    int rowNumber=5;
    List<WebElement> listRowRadioButton = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table>tbody>tr:nth-child("+rowNumber+")>td>input[type='radio']"));


    //Get All Radio Button Checked of specfic Row
    //for example in your case to get all radio button of SSN ROW
    rowNumber=5;
    List<WebElement> listRowRadioButtonChecked = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table>tbody>tr:nth-child("+rowNumber+")>td>input[type='radio']:checked"));        
}
```

Hope so you get what you want. 
if any issue then let me know.
Thanks.